# Rails: Keeping a partial DRY when using locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, locals

I have partial that is being reused by a couple controllers.

Right now I have this partial set up to accept 2 objects which I don't want to do.

```
-if @article
  .main-inner
    .article-header
      .article-title
        =@article.title
      -if !@article.byline.blank?
        %span#byline
          =@article.byline
      %span#timestamp
        =@article.publish_date.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %Z")
    .article-content
      =truncate(@article.content, :length => 600).html_safe
-else
  .main-inner
    .article-header
      .article-title
        =article.title
      -if !article.byline.blank?
        %span#byline
          =article.byline
      %span#timestamp
        =article.publish_date.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %Z")
    .article-content
      =truncate(article.content, :length => 600).html_safe
```

When @article

```
def show
  @article = Article.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
end
```

When through locals

```
$("#article").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'article/view', :locals => { :article => @newarticle }) %>")
```

1) How can I consolidate my partial to not use if @article.
2) In my js.  What is the proper syntax for rendering partials so I don't have to say :partial => 'article/view' and use :locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a partial then you should use article(local) instead of @article(not instant variable), and should always pass it in locals when render the partial.

```
render(:partial => 'article/view', :locals => { :article => @article })
```

or

```
render(:partial => 'article/view', :locals => { :article => @newarticle })
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand and realized what I had to do.  Thanks!